# Rails and Omniauth - How much data from the authentication hash should I be saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I am currently using rails and the omniauth gem to integrate my application with facebook, twitter and linkedin. When I process an omniauth callback I simply save uid and provider from the authentication hash. Most tutorials online only save these fields as well but how would you be able to access the users details from facebook/twitter/linkedin later on? What other fields from the authentication hash should be saved other than uid/provider?

Some guides I have read:

[Github omniauth with devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)

[Railscast omniauth and devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised)

Answer (score 3):

In the Railscast there is an example before creating full-functional OmniauthCallbacksController , where the line :

```
raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
```

outputs the request on the screen . As you can see , in this hash ,`omniauth.auth`, there is a lot of useful information about the authenticated user . It is received each time the authentication is OK . In this case there is no need to store anything else in your database except `uid` and `provider` .

The entries of the hash are accessible like this :

```
(request.env["omniauth.auth"]).info.nickname
```

or

```
(request.env["omniauth.auth"]).uid
```

You see the logic : every section of the yaml output (let's say `info') contains specific attributes .

Comment: Well I would like to be able to access the user's data anytime, not just when he authenticates

Comment: The hash is available until the sign_out moment .

Comment: ah. ok thats the source of my confusion. Thanks

Comment: How can you access the hash? Do I need to put it into session?

Comment: request.env["omniauth.auth"] is empty though after the user's local account is created

Comment: Am I right in saying the request.env["omniauth.auth"] is only available in the one callback request? If you don't store it's information elsewhere, and your controller action redirects or you visit another action, the hash is gone. So you can use @RumenMilushev's answer but only in the action used for the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up saving the access token from facebook, polling the api if I needed info and then automatically refreshing the token every 2 hours.